# IText Center the heading in pdf

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to create a report using the below program. Things work fine but I'm unable to center the header "VEHICLE AVAILABILITY LISTING (VAL) AS OF 11/05/2014"

I want to center the heading as well want spacing around it...Ideally, it should span 5 columns, well centered and bolded..

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCellEvent;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTableEvent;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

/**
 * First iText example: Hello World.
 */
public class HelloWorld implements PdfPCellEvent, PdfPTableEvent{

    /** Path to the resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT
        = "c:/itext/hello.pdf";

    /**
     * Creates a PDF file: hello.pdf
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws DocumentException, IOException {
        new HelloWorld().createPdf(RESULT);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
     * @param filename the path to the new PDF document
     * @throws    DocumentException 
     * @throws    IOException 
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename)
    throws DocumentException, IOException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        document.add(getheaderTable(writer));
        document.add(getTable());
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }
    public PdfPTable getheaderTable(PdfWriter writer) throws DocumentException, IOException{
        HelloWorld gp = new HelloWorld();
        PdfPTable headertable = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 5 });
        headertable.setTableEvent(gp);
        headertable.setWidthPercentage(100f);
        headertable.getDefaultCell().setCellEvent(new HelloWorld());

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("VEHICLE AVAILABILITY LISTING (VAL) AS OF 11/05/2014"));
        cell.setColspan(5);
        cell.setRowspan(5);
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
        headertable.addCell(cell);
        return headertable;
}
    public PdfPTable getTable() throws DocumentException, IOException {
        HelloWorld gp = new HelloWorld();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 5, 1, 1, 1});
        table.setTableEvent(gp);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
        table.getDefaultCell().setPadding(5);
        table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        table.getDefaultCell().setCellEvent(gp);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                table.addCell("CARS");
                table.addCell("MODEL");
                table.addCell("OPENDATE");
                table.addCell("CLOSEOUT DATE");
        }
        table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(null);
        //table.setHeaderRows(1);
        //table.setFooterRows(1);
        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        Car c =  new Car("SUV 4 * 4", "FORD ENDEAVOR",new Timestamp(date.getTime()),new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        System.out.println(c);
        cars.add(c);
        cars.add(new Car("TRUCK 4 * 4", "GM CHEVY",new Timestamp(date.getTime()),new Timestamp(date.getTime())));
        for (Car car : cars) {
                table.addCell(car.getItemDesc());
                table.addCell(car.getModel());
                table.addCell(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(car.getOpen_Date()));
                table.addCell(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(car.getCloseout_Date()));
        }
        return table;
}
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
            PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
    float x1 = position.getLeft() + 2;
    float x2 = position.getRight() - 2;
    float y1 = position.getTop() - 2;
    float y2 = position.getBottom() + 2;
    PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
    canvas.rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
    canvas.stroke();
}
    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] width, float[] height,
            int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
    float widths[] = width[0];
    float x1 = widths[0];
    float x2 = widths[widths.length - 1];
    float y1 = height[0];
    float y2 = height[height.length - 1];
    PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
    cb.rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
    cb.stroke();
    cb.resetRGBColorStroke();
}
}

class Car{
    protected String ItemDesc;
    protected String Model;
    protected Timestamp Open_Date;
    protected Timestamp Closeout_Date;
    public Car(String ItemDesc, String Model,Timestamp Open_Date, Timestamp Closeout_Date){
        this.ItemDesc = ItemDesc;
        this.Model = Model;
        this.Open_Date = Open_Date;
        this.Closeout_Date = Closeout_Date;
    }
    public String getItemDesc() {
        return ItemDesc;
    }
    public void setItemDesc(String itemDesc) {
        ItemDesc = itemDesc;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return Model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        Model = model;
    }
    public Timestamp getOpen_Date() {
        return Open_Date;
    }
    public void setOpen_Date(Timestamp open_Date) {
        Open_Date = open_Date;
    }
    public Timestamp getCloseout_Date() {
        return Closeout_Date;
    }
    public void setCloseout_Date(Timestamp closeout_Date) {
        Closeout_Date = closeout_Date;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** You want to center the text inside a cell (that uses *text mode*) horizontally.

That is done using:

```
cell.setHorizontalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Note that this property (horizontal alignment) will be ignored the moment you use a cell in *compostie mode*. In *composite mode*, the horizontal alignment defined at the level of the cell is ignored in favor of the alignment at the level of the individual elements added to that cell.

**Problem 2:** You want the text to be in bold.

Currently, you are creating a `Phrase` like this:

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("VEHICLE AVAILABILITY LISTING (VAL) AS OF 11/05/2014");
```

This creates a text element with font Helvetica (regular). To use a bold font, you need:

```
Font bold = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("VEHICLE AVAILABILITY LISTING (VAL) AS OF 11/05/2014", bold);
```

**Problem 3:** You want a specific cell to have a minimum height.

Currently, you are creating a table with 5 columns. The first row consists of a single cell with colspan 5. Hence, this cell spans the entire row. You define a rowspan of 5 for this cell. That is absurd. Try this in HTML and see what happens. The height of the row is not affected (for obvious reasons). Please remove the following line from your code (because it doesn't make sense):

```
cell.setRowspan(5);
```

Suppose that you are using a font of size 12, then the height of the line will be 18 by default. You want a height of about 5 lines, so you need 90 and let's add some padding and work with a height of 100. In that case, you should add the following line:

```
cell.setMinimumHeight(100);
```

**Bonus problem:**

You may experience that the text isn't perfectly centered vertically. That's because of some assumptions that are made by iText. Sometimes it helps if you tell the cell to take into account some specific font metrics, such as the Ascent and the Descent of the font:

cell.setUseAscender(true);
   cell.setUseDescender(true);

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a call to  `cell.setHorizontalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_CENTER);`

You may also use `cell.setColspan(5);`